# JavaScript if statement optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I have the following code:

```
      function() {
         if (foo && foo.bar !== baz) { //needed because foo can be undefined, so foo.bar always returns value
            function1()
            return;
         }

         if (foo) {
            function2()
         } else {
            function1()
         }
      }
```

I was wondering, what would be the best way to optimize these if statements, from code structure point of view.

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Try `foo && foo.baz === baz ? function2() : function1()`.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Don't waste your time on this unless your profiling has determined that it's the bottleneck.

Comment: Can you please delete it. My bad!

Comment: @Barmar, actually, the question is about how to organise code, not optimize the performance. Always good idea to have a clean, readable code.

Comment: @Mathletics This is example code and would be closed as off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: You can flag your own question for moderator attention and ask them to delete it for you if you can't yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be converted into a one-liner:

```
foo && foo.baz === baz ? function2() : function1();
```

If `foo` is falsey then it will execute `function1` and if `foo` is truthy but `foo.baz !== baz` then it will still execute `function1`. Otherwise, it will execute `function2`.

The reason this works is because if `foo` is truthy and `foo.baz !== baz` is `false` then `function2` is only executed if `foo.baz === baz` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Might be:

```
if ((foo && foo.bar !== baz) || !foo) {
  function1();
} else {
  function2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((foo && foo.bar !== baz) || !foo) ? funtion1() : function2());
```

Answer (score 1):

An example could be:

```
if (!foo || foo.bar !== baz) {
  function1();
} else {
  function2();
}
```

Similar to kamituel's one, but shorter, and maybe easier to read.

Comment: Oh yeah, I actually didn't noticed that ;) +1